# Is there free software that can bulk process the length and bitrate of mp3s?

Tags: windows, mp3

I'm looking for free windows software that I can use to create 20s clips of a large number of mp3s. Ideally I would be able to enter the desired settings once, and have the software process all of the mp3s.

The specific parameters that I would like control of are:

- Length.
- Quality
- File type (I would like to convert the mp3s to ogg format)

Comment: I believe `lame` can be programmed (using a batch file or other method) to process files, but I'm not sure about Ogg format.

Answer (score 4):

[FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/autobuilds/ffmpeg/mingw32/static/) is an open source media "swiss army knife".  It can handle exactly what you're looking for, but it does require using the command prompt.

First [download FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/autobuilds/ffmpeg/mingw32/static/), any recent release will do.  You'll need a program to extract the 7z archive.  I recommend [WinRAR](http://www.win-rar.com/download.html) (free trial).  Extract ffmpeg to a folder, I used c:\ffmpeg.

Next open the command prompt (start > run > cmd.exe).  And do the following (again, assuming ffmpeg was extracted to c:\ffmpeg.

```
c:\Users\media> cd c:\ffmpeg\bin

c:\ffmpeg\bin> for /r c:\Users\media\Music %i in (*.mp3) do ffmpeg -i "%i" -ss 0 -t 20 -aq 0 -y -acodec libvorbis "%i_clip.ogg"
```

Change "c:\Users\media\Music" to the folder that contains mp3's you want to create clips for.  Refer to the ffmpeg manual for instructions on the various options (-aq = quality, -ss = skip seconds into file, -t = time in seconds)

Comment: Eh, use 7zip to decompress the 7z file. It's free and not just as a trial (so no nagging) and it'll handle any type of compression out there. And it's fast.

Otherwise, ditto what he said.

Answer (score 0):

FFMPEG is a good choice as h0twfr3 says. If you prefer a GUI, an Audacious "chain" can also do what you want.